# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADMobileAds"

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, ads

I'm trying to insert Google ADs in my first App.
The compiler shows me this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADMobileAds", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I checked everything (linkers, targeting and building settings) but the error is showing anyway.
How can I do?

```
Ld /Users/giacomodebenedetto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dadi_Risiko-gduboeipnoxpmuedhluilxlszian/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dadi\ Risiko.app/Dadi\ Risiko normal arm64 (in target: Dadi Risiko)
    cd /Users/giacomodebenedetto/Library/Autosave\ Information/Dadi\ Risiko
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=12.2
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk -L/Users/giacomodebenedetto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dadi_Risiko-gduboeipnoxpmuedhluilxlszian/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/giacomodebenedetto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dadi_Risiko-gduboeipnoxpmuedhluilxlszian/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/giacomodebenedetto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dadi_Risiko-gduboeipnoxpmuedhluilxlszian/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities -F/Users/giacomodebenedetto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dadi_Risiko-gduboeipnoxpmuedhluilxlszian/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/nanopb -F/Users/giacomodebenedetto/Library/Autosave\ Information/Dadi\ Risiko/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/giacomodebenedetto/Library/Autosave\ Information/Dadi\ Risiko/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -filelist /Users/giacomodebenedetto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dadi_Risiko-gduboeipnoxpmuedhluilxlszian/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Dadi\ Risiko.build/Debug-iphoneos/Dadi\ Risiko.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Dadi\ Risiko.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=12.2 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/giacomodebenedetto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dadi_Risiko-gduboeipnoxpmuedhluilxlszian/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Dadi\ Risiko.build/Debug-iphoneos/Dadi\ Risiko.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Dadi\ Risiko_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/giacomodebenedetto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dadi_Risiko-gduboeipnoxpmuedhluilxlszian/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Dadi\ Risiko.build/Debug-iphoneos/Dadi\ Risiko.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Dadi_Risiko.swiftmodule -ObjC -framework Pods_Dadi_Risiko -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/giacomodebenedetto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dadi_Risiko-gduboeipnoxpmuedhluilxlszian/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Dadi\ Risiko.build/Debug-iphoneos/Dadi\ Risiko.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Dadi\ Risiko_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/giacomodebenedetto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dadi_Risiko-gduboeipnoxpmuedhluilxlszian/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dadi\ Risiko.app/Dadi\ Risiko

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADMobileAds", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```